# Bot framework V4 Subscribe to receive conversation Id on Javascript

Tags: javascript, bots, chatbot, botframework

I am using directline with webchat.

```
window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
   {
      directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
         secret: '<my secret key>',
      }),
      //customizing web chat styles.
      styleOptions: styleOptions
   },
   document.getElementById('webchat')
);
```

This my javascript that initiates the webchat with the secret key. Is there anyway that I can receive the conversationId back in the javascript after initializing the webchat as above?

Answer (score 0):

This is easily achieved by utilizing the method demonstrated in the [04.api/a.welcome-event](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/a.welcome-event) sample. Upon Web Chat connecting, an event is sent to the bot indicating this. When the event is received by the bot the bot sends a return activity. The return activity, by design, includes the `conversationID`.

In short, here is the code you can reference. Taken from the sample, this sends the users location based on the browser's properties.

From Web Chat:

```
https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/a.welcome-event
```

From the bot:

```
if (context.activity.name === 'webchat/join') {
  await context.sendActivity(
    `Got \`webchat/join\` event, your language is \`${(context.activity.value || {}).language}\``
  );
}
```